# Loop through columns

Tags: r, loops

To estimate the independent effect of pm10 and o3 on a single outcome (death in the code) I could use a script found below. In this model the effects of  "pm10" and "o3" on death are estimated separately. Now if I have several outcomes how can I modify this script to accommodate this situation?  In the example data set the outcomes of interest are death, cvd and resp and my aim is to run one model for each of these by alternatively using “pm10" and "o3" as predictors. Thus I expect to run 6 models (e.g. two models for cvd:-one with pm10 and one with 03).

```
  library(quantmod)
    library(mgcv)
    library(dlnm) 
    df <- chicagoNMMAPS
    #out<- c("death", "cvd", "resp ")

    varlist0 <- c("pm10", "o3")
    m1 <- lapply(varlist0,function(v) {
        f <- sprintf("death~ s(time,bs='cr',k=200)+s(temp,bs='cr') + Lag(%s,0:6)",v)
        gam(as.formula(f),family=quasipoisson,na.action=na.omit,data=df) 
      })
```

Comment: You should construct the formula object a bit differently. I would try something along the lines of (not in a loop) `gam(death ~ s(time, bs = "cr", k = 200) + s(temp, bs = "cr", l Lag(pm10, 0:6) + Lag(o3, 0:6)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cross-posted this question on R-help@r-project.org mailing list and Rui Barradas provided the following answer. The code works correctly, but I find it a bit slow on my data.

```
m1 <- lapply(varlist0,function(v) { 
        lapply(outcomes, function(o){ 
          f <- sprintf("%s~ s(time,bs='cr',k=200)+s(temp,bs='cr') + Lag(%s,0:6)", o, v) 
                gam(as.formula(f),family=quasipoisson,na.action=na.omit,data=df) 
       })}) 

m1 <- unlist(m1, recursive = FALSE) 
m1
```